# I want to use a logic like this that does not work, why not working

Tags: javascript

I want to use a logic like this that does not work, why not working

```
var a = '1==2';
if( a )
{
    alert(1);

} else {
    alert(2);

}
```

My Code

```
var arr_logic = {};
arr_logic['rst_content_padding'] = ['rst_general_wrapper', '1==2'];
$.each(arr_logic, function(i, val) {
  if (val[1]) {
    alert(1);
  } else {
    alert(2);
  }
});
```

Comment: remove quotes, i.e `a = 1==2`

Answer (score 0):

Dont put your boolean in a string :

```
var a = 1==2;
if( a )
{
    alert(1);

} else {
    alert(2);

}
```

Comment: var arr_logic = {};
arr_logic['rst_content_padding'] = ['rst_general_wrapper', '1==2'];
$.each( arr_logic, function( i, val ) {
 if( val[1] )
 {
  alert(1);
  
 } else {
  alert(2);
  
 }

});

Answer (score 0):

just change your code to this :

```
var a = (1==2);
if( a )
{
    alert(1);
} else {
   alert(2);
}
```

Comment: var arr_logic = {};
arr_logic['rst_content_padding'] = ['rst_general_wrapper', '1==2'];
$.each( arr_logic, function( i, val ) {
 if( val[1] )
 {
  alert(1);
  
 } else {
  alert(2);
  
 }

});help me

Answer (score 0):

Non-empty string in JavaScript are truthy, which means their value is `true` when evaluated in a boolean context (the `if` statement tries to get a boolean value out of the expression you give to it).

To actually evaluate the expression itself, you must not put it in quotes to create a string, but just leave it without the quotes: `1==2`. JavaScript now evaluates this expression to `false` (because 1 is not equal to 2), and will alert 2:

```js
var a = 1==2;
if (a) {
  alert(1);
} else {
  alert(2);
}
```

By the way, in most cases, you should use the identity operator to check if two values are equal: `1 === 2` instead of `1 == 2`.

Comment: var arr_logic = {};
arr_logic['rst_content_padding'] = ['rst_general_wrapper', '1==2'];
$.each( arr_logic, function( i, val ) {
 if( val[1] )
 {
  alert(1);
  
 } else {
  alert(2);
  
 }

}); help me

Comment: What's the problem? Consider asking a new SO question.

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can convert String to executable code in JavaScript by using eval()

```
var a = '1==2';
if( eval(a) )
{
    alert(1);

} else {
    alert(2);

}
```

Comment: Eval ... is evil!

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/86513/why-is-using-the-javascript-eval-function-a-bad-idea) SO question explains a few reasons why to not use eval.

Answer (score 0):

All you are missing is including a jQuery Library.

Include it from any of the CDN like code.jQuery or googleapis

Try this snippet.

```js
var arr_logic = {};
arr_logic['rst_content_padding'] = ['rst_general_wrapper', 1==2];
$.each(arr_logic, function(i, val) {
  if (val[1]) {
    alert(1);
  } else {
    alert(2);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```